# Validation in SSIS package creation giving error: "xxcolumnnamexx". Cannot insert into a row version column

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms

I am trying to copy hundreds of tables from one SQL Serdatabase to another. I don't have access to the backup files or the server's file system. The tables have a timestamp column called ts. I am using the Export Data wizard to create a file based dtsx file. During the validation step, it gives an error "ts". Cannot insert into a row version column. And the wizard stops going forward.
I understand why I get the error. The issue is because of the number of tables, I can't manually go to each table and set the timestamp column to 'ignore'. It's very time consuming.

I wanted the dtsx file to get created and then I have a little program I wrote which edits the file to ignore those columns.

Is there a way to disable the validation process or a way to get around the timestamp issue for so many tables? 
My other option is to delete all the timestamp columns from the source tables. I don't care about the values in those columns.  (Using SSMS 17.3)

Answer (score 0):

In destination database you can alter all timestamp columns to binary(8)  - to do it automatically you can make procedure for that, generating alter commands.

Then there will be no problem with copying value from timestamp to binary(8) column, and no error should occur (and you will keep values from it but will be stored in different datatype).